# Can i add a folder inside a document library which reference a folder inside another site

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, content-type

I want to add a folder to a document library, but the folder is a folder inside another site. i find a way to add a link inside the document library >> which reference the folder inside the second site, as follow:-

[image]

But the layout of the generated item will be a link inside the document library and not a folder. so is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge that is not a supported scenario and that is not doable in SharePoint Online.

Comment: so the only option is to add a link inside the document library? as shown in my question?

Comment: @SharePointTestDev As far as I know this is the way it works.